# How to call a tree with a single branch?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

How do you call a tree with only one branch (in other words, where every vertex has maximum one direct successor)?

Comment: In graph theory, such graphs are called paths I think.

Answer (score 4):

A connected graph with two vertices of degree one and the rest of degree two is called a [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)).

If you want to distinguish between successor and predecessor vertices, you can [direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) the edges all the same direction and obtain a directed path.